# Examples of integration by parts that work both ways

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Usually, integration by parts only works one way. For example, evaluating $\int xe^x\,dx$ can only be done by differentiating $x$ and integrating $e^x$, but not the other way round, since $\int x^2e^x\,dx$ makes it more difficult than the original integral.

However, the integral $$\int x\ln x\,dx$$ can be evaluated using integration by parts both ways:

$$\int x\ln x\,dx=x\int \ln x\,dx - \int\left(x'\int\ln x\,dx\right)\,dx=x^2(\ln x-1)-\int x(\ln x-1)\,dx$$ and (directly), $$\int x\ln x\,dx=\ln x\int x\,dx-\int\left(\ln'x\int x\,dx\right)\,dx=\frac{x^2}2\ln x-\int\frac x2\,dx.$$

There are also trigonometric integrals that can do this. For instance, an integral consisting of $\sin$ and $\cos$, as $\int \sin = -\cos$ and $\int \cos = \sin$: $$\int \sin2x\cos3x\,dx.$$

@JamesArathoon has provided this one as well: $$\int x\arctan x\,dx$$

> **What are some other examples of integrals that have this property as well?**
>
> I believe that such integrals are rather rare, so I don't want 'similar' integrals like multiplying by a constant or adding $1$ to the integrand.
>
> Of course, integrands of forms other than $xf(x)$ would be even better (and more challenging :)

Comment: The other two obvious functions to mention with many analogous properties in common with $\sin$ and $\cos$, including integrating to one another, are $\sinh$ and $\cosh$.

Comment: $\int x\; arctanh\; x \;dx$ follows as a corollary from your intro, but the analogous function $\int x\;\arctan x \;dx$ also integrates by parts both ways.

Comment: There is (or should be) a name to this sort of integral where choice of u and v is like this (ie, more than one way to solve by by-parts)

Comment: @Nick Perhaps. It would be great if there were. Congrats for persevering with the election btw :)

Comment: There is a rather silly example: one could prove that
$$\int x^n \, dx = \frac {x^{n+1}} {n+1} + c$$
by induction on $n$ using integration by parts in the inductive step, writing $x^{n+1}$ as $x \cdot x^n$ or even as $x^h \cdot x^k$ with $h, k \le n$ and choosing either power as the finite or differential factor.

Comment: @LucaBressan True, but as you have said it isn't really what I'm after :)

Comment: wouldn't there be many cases where it is true for $\int f(x)g(x)h(x)dx$?

Comment: or perhaps $\int e^{2x}dx=\int e^x e^x dx$

Comment: in your example with $\int x\ln x dx$, in the indirect method you are still using IBP for $\int \ln x dx$ (of direct method), so it looks circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we wish for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that we can evaluate $\int f(x) g(x) dx$ using integration by parts in two ways, either by **A**:

$$\int f(x) g(x) dx = g(x)\int f(x) dx - \int (g'(x) \int f(x) dx ) dx $$

... or by **B**:

$$\int f(x) g(x) dx = f(x)\int g(x) dx - \int (f'(x) \int g(x) dx ) dx $$

In the following list, **(i)** to **(iii)** are put forward by yourself, **(iv)** and **(v)** are trivial examples from the comments, and **(vi)** and **(vii)** are new.

**(i)** $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \mathrm{ln}(x)$

**(ii)** $f(x) = \mathrm{sin}(mx) $ and $g(x) =\mathrm{cos}(nx) $ for $n \neq m$

**(iii)** $f(x) = x $ and $g(x) = \mathrm{arctan}(x) $

**(iv)** $f(x) = x^n $ and $g(x) = x^m $

**(v)** $f(x) = e^{nx} $ and $g(x) = e^{mx} $

**(vi)** $f(x) = e^{nx} $ and $g(x) = \mathrm{sin}(mx) $

**(vii)** $f(x) = x $ and $g(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$

Other examples can be made by switching around some trig and hyperbolic functions (e.g. $\mathrm{sin}$ and $\mathrm{cos}$ for $\mathrm{sinh}$ and $\mathrm{cosh}$ in **(ii)** or $\mathrm{arctan}$ for $\mathrm{arcsin}$ in **(iii)**).

It sometimes seems the case that one of the directions **A** or **B** is much easier than the other. I think this is true of **(i)**, **(iii)** and **(vii)** (and I have written them so that **A** is easier than **B**).

For all of the examples except for the trivial **(iv)** and **(v)**, at least one of **A** and **B** require the use of the "indirect method", where the integrand $\int f(x)g(x) dx$ is found again on the RHS and the expression is rearranged to get $\alpha \int f(x)g(x) dx$ on the LHS with $\alpha \neq 1$.

So far I cannot spot any other interesting similarities between these examples... Perhaps others can, or could add to the list?

**Edit: another example**

**(viii)** $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\mathrm{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int^{x}_0 e^{-t^2} dt$

(We can show that $ \int \mathrm{erf}(x) dx = x\mathrm{erf}(x) + \frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} + C $ by another application of integration by parts, and $\frac{d}{dx} \mathrm{erf}(x)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2} $ fairly trivially.)

Interestingly, evaluating **(viii)** using **B** requires use of the “indirect method” again.

I also tried using $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\Gamma (x)$, but the integral is undefined.

**Edit: proof of equivalence of methods A and B when $f(x)=x$**

@farruhota suggests in the comments that **(i)** might be based on some sort of circular argument, as $\int \mathrm{ln}(x) dx $ is often itself evaluated using integration by parts. The same could be said of $\int \mathrm{arctan}(x) dx$ in **(iii)** and of $\int \mathrm{erf}(x) dx$ in **(viii)**. I now believe that this is true and is very much linked to why the "indirect method" keeps cropping up in method **B**. I offer the following proof.

Let $f(x)=x$. Then method **A** goes:

$$ 
\begin{align}
I(x) &:= \int^x_0 tg(t) dt 
\\ &= \frac{1}{2}x^2 g(x)-\frac{1}{2} \int^x_0 t^2 g'(t) dt \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{align}
$$

... and the integral $\int^x_0 t^2 g'(t) dt$ must then be evaluated.

(Note that I am now using limits of integration in order to make my workings more rigorous.)

Method **B** begins instead:

$$
\begin{align}
I(x) &= \int^x_0 tg(t)dt 
\\ &= x \int^x_0 g(t)dt - \int^x_0 \left( \int^t_0 g(s)ds \right) dt \qquad \qquad (2)
\end{align}
$$

Now I'll use integration by parts again in order to evaluate $\int^x_0 g(t)dt$ and $\int^t_0 g(s)ds$, so that $(2)$ follows on as:

$$
\begin{align}
I(x) &= x \left( xg(x)-\int^x_0 tg'(t)dt \right) - \int^x_0 \left( tg(t) - \int^t_0 sg'(s)ds \right) dt
\\ &= x^2g(x) - x \int^x_0 tg'(t)dt - I(x) + \int^x_0 \int^t_0 sg'(s)ds \, dt 
\end{align}
$$

Now here's where the "indirect method" comes in. We can collect $I(x)$ onto the LHS and divide by $2$ so that:

$$
I(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^2g(x) - \frac{1}{2} \underbrace{ \left( x \int^x_0 tg'(t)dt - \int^x_0 \int^t_0 sg'(s)ds \, dt \right) }_{=:K(x)}  \qquad \qquad (3)
$$

Focus now on $K(x)$. Write $h(t):=tg'(t)$ so that:

$$
\begin{align}
K(x) &= x \int^x_0 h(t)dt - \int^x_0 \int^t_0 h(s)ds \, dt
\\ &= \int^x_0 th(t) dt
\\ &= \int^x_0 t^2g'(t)
\end{align}
$$

... where I've used integration by parts "backwards" to get from line 1 to line 2.

Putting this back into $(3)$, we get:

$$ I(x)= \frac{1}{2}x^2 g(x)-\frac{1}{2} \int^x_0 t^2 g'(t) dt \qquad \qquad (4)$$

... which is exactly the same as method **A** at $(1)$!

Both methods **A** and **B** boil down to whether we can evaluate $\int^x_0 t^2 g'(t) dt$. I hence offer the following as a (partial) answer to the question.

If $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)$ is such that we can evaluate $\int x^2 g'(x) dx$ then $\int f(x) g(x) dx$ can be integrated by parts "both ways".

**Claim: A and B are *always* equivalent**

Now, you suggest finding examples where $f(x)$ is not just equal to $x$.

If equations $(2)$ to $(4)$ are worked through with a general $f(x)$ instead of with $f(x)=x$ then the following can be obtained:

$$ \int^x_0 f(t)g(t)dt = xf(x)g(x) - \int^x_0 tf'(t)g(t)dt - \int^x_0 tf(t)g'(t)dt \qquad (5) $$

Note that $f(x)=x$ worked nicely because $f(x)=kx \iff tf'(t)=f(t)$ and so the second term on the RHS of $(5)$ becomes $I(x)$.

Also note that $(5)$ is symmetric in $f$ and $g$. It can be obtained by beginning with either route **A** or **B**. I would hence conclude that routes **A** and **B** are *always* equivalent:

route **A** can be used iff **B** can be used, as both can be manipulated into $(5)$

(However, one of these routes might be *much* longer than the other.)

Comment: Very interesting answer! Do you mean that the property holds if $\int x^2g'(x)\,dx$ can be evaluated *without* integration by parts?

Comment: I don't think it matters. In examples **(i)**, **(iii)** and **(vii)**, integration by parts is not needed again to evaluate $\int x^2g'(x)dx$ (instead, substitutions are required for **(iii)** and **(vii)** while **(i)** is trivial). However, another nice application of integration by parts is needed to evaluate $\int x^2g'(x)dx = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx$ in **(viii)** (with one of the "parts" being $x$ and the other being $xe^{-x^2}$ and the solution being in terms of $\mathrm{erf}(x)$).

Comment: But what about $g(x)=e^x$? Since $\int x^2e^x\,dx$ can be evaluated using IBP, does that mean it satisfies the property?

Comment: I think this is a difficulty in working with such a loose definition. What do you think? It seems like evaluating $\int x^2e^xdx$ using IBP (with one part $x^2$ and one part $e^x$) is "cheating" because it's like taking one step forward and two steps back. But evaluating $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int x^2e^{-x^2}dx$ (with one part $x$ and one part $xe^{-x^2}$) seems fine because because you're not going back on yourself.